# Java - Docker fails to install dependencies - Html2Pdf library

Tags: java, spring, docker, dockerfile, html2pdf

I am building a Java application that I will be hosting in a docker container. Part of this application is to use this library:

https://github.com/wooio/htmltopdf-java

It takes a URL and converts it to a PDF document. However, when running the `.jar` file through docker I get the error that it's missing native dependencies:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so': Native library (tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so) not found in resource path`

This is documented in the last section of the link above, that it needs these libraries to run correctly:

- libc6 (or glibc) libx11 libxext libxrender libstdc++ libssl1.0
  freetype fontconfig

I have modified my `Dockerfile` to try to install these dependencies at the docker build:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

RUN sh -c 'apk update && apk add libssl1.0 libx11 libxext libxrender libstdc++ freetype fontconfig'

COPY server/target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

I am new to docker, but I found this snippet of code in an issue of the [github repo](https://github.com/wooio/htmltopdf-java/issues/7). But I still cannot get it to work.

Can you spot the issue here why I cannot run the program?

### Edit:

I am still getting the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so': Native library (tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so) not found in resource path`

But when SSHing into the Docker container and looking into the `tmp`-folder the `io.woo.htmltopdf`-library is listed. The path `tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so` also exists in the docker container.

Could it be something with the path settings? That the Java application is not using the correct path somehow?

The `app.jar` that is being run is located in the root folder, where the `tmp` folder is also located - so it should find it?

Comment: can you provide me with the jar and any other steps than building the image so i can test this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do a workaround to this problem by using the native `wkhtmltopdf` library together with the [wkhtmltopdf java wrapper](https://github.com/jhonnymertz/java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper).

Answer (score 1):

I have also had problem with the alpine images, if you don't mind about the size of the image, I would try to use `openjdk:8` as your provided image instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. When using `openjdk:8` I instead get the error `sh: 1: apk: not found` . And when running the app without the `apk add` command I still get the `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so': Native library (tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so) not found in resource path`

Answer (score 1):

Alpine Linux is built on musl libc, not glibc. My guess is that your native library is not compatible with musl.

You can try the `openjdk:8-slim` instead. This one is built on Debian, it is slightly bigger than the alpine-based image, but it will be able to run libraries built for glibc.

You need to use apt to install additional packages, and a bit of research is needed to find which packages provide the libraries you need.

Try starting your Dockerfile with the following lines instead :

```
FROM openjdk:8-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      libc6 \
      libx11-6 \
      libxext6 \
      libxrender1 \
      libstdc++ \
      libssl1.0 \
      libfreetype6 \
      fontconfig \
   && apt-get clean \
   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

This generates a 1.37 Gb image though, most of which is from the installation of libstdc++ and all of its dependencies. There might be an opportunity for optimization here (do you really need the full C++ Stdlib for your application to function properly ?). Without this package, the image size drops to 256 Mb.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried the solution above, but I am still getting the `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so': Native library (tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so) not found in resource path` error. When i SSH into the docker container the wkhtmltopdf dependencies are in the `tmp/` folder, so I don't understand why I keep getting this error.

Comment: Probobably your libwkhtmltox.so is missing one of its dependencies. run `objdump -p libwkhtmltox.so` to check required libraries, and make sure all of them are installed. You'll probably need to add another package to the apt-get install command.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, by the way I used `htmltopdf` version `1.0.8` but it's working on mac os, but when I used images `docker.io/fabric8/s2i-java:3.0-java8` it's not working and then I try to down version to `1.0.6` and it's working

change

```
compile group: 'io.woo', name: 'htmltopdf', version: '1.0.8'
```

to

```
compile group: 'io.woo', name: 'htmltopdf', version: '1.0.6'
```